ts-jest tests randomly failing due to parser?
I'm trying to execute some tests with ts-jest.
The problem is that the parser sometimes breaks and throws errors that don't make any sense, like in the image.
It could be important to say that it only happens in files that I've done some modification.
But then it doesn't matter if I return them to their previous state; parser just breaks.
I'm currently running TypeScript 4.9.5 with TS-Jest 29.0.5 on a NestJS application.


Thank you in advance

Try turning on editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters in VSCode settings to see if there are some invisible chars
